# Script to automatically save a PSD when saving a PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, photoshop-scripting

Can you give me a script which will save a PSD automatically when I save a PNG?
I found a script that saves a PNG when saving a PSD, I tried to reverse it but it didn't work :(

```
main(); 
function main(){ 
    var Name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, ''); 
    var Ext = decodeURI(app.activeDocument.name).replace(/^.*\./,''); 
    if(Ext.toLowerCase() != 'psd') return; 
    var Path = app.activeDocument.path; 
    var saveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".png"); 
    if(saveFile.exists) saveFile.remove(); 
    SavePNG(saveFile); 
} 

function SavePNG(saveFile){ 
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); 
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above doesn't have a function to save out a PSD. Your code assumes that the psd already exists.

Try this

```
main(); 

function main()
{ 

    var Name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, ''); 
    var Ext = decodeURI(app.activeDocument.name).replace(/^.*\./,''); 
    if(Ext.toLowerCase() != 'psd') return;

    // assumes the file has already been saved
    var Path = app.activeDocument.path; 

    // Save as PSD
    var SaveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".psd"); 
    if(SaveFile.exists) SaveFile.remove(); 
    SavePSD(SaveFile);

    // Save as PNG
    SaveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".png"); 
    if(SaveFile.exists) SaveFile.remove(); 
    SavePNG(SaveFile);

    alert("File saved as .png and .psd");
} 

function SavePNG(saveFile)
{ 
  var pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); 
  activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
}

function SavePSD(saveFile)
{
  var psdFile = new File(saveFile);
  psdSaveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
  psdSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  psdSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;  
  activeDocument.saveAs(psdFile, psdSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```